# How to change Job Group and Description in Spark UI triggered by Zeppelin Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have searched around for this and found that you can do

```
sc.setJobGroup("job group", "job description")
```

but with Zeppelin spark SQL interpreter, how would you do it? You can't use variables like `sc` in the SQL paragraph.

I have tried setting the jobGroup in another `spark` paragraph in the same notebook, but that doesn't seem to affect the `sql` interpreter.

I have also tried extending `SparkInterpreter` and `SparkSqlInterpreter` classes (basically the exact same copy except that I modify the `sc.setJobGroup` call). This worked for `spark` but not `spark.sql`. I'm really baffled by this. Has anybody been able to do this successfully?